# How to list all submodules and their classes of PyQt?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I'm trying to recursively list all classes of PyQt5:

```
PyQt5.QtWidgets
PyQt5.QtWidgets.QPushButton
PyQt5.QtWidgets.QLabel
PyQt5.QtCore
PyQt5.QtCore.QPoint
and so on...
```

This is what I have now:

```
import pkgutil

package = __import__('PyQt5')
for importer, modname, ispkg in pkgutil.walk_packages(
        path=package.__path__,
        prefix=package.__name__ + '.',
        onerror=lambda x: None):
    print(modname)
```

This, however, doesn't give me e.g. all the classes under `QtWidgets` or anything under `QtCore`:

```
PyQt5.Enginio
PyQt5.Qt
PyQt5.QtBluetooth
PyQt5.QtCore
PyQt5.QtDBus
PyQt5.QtDesigner
PyQt5.QtGui
PyQt5.QtHelp
PyQt5.QtLocation
PyQt5.QtMultimedia
PyQt5.QtMultimediaWidgets
PyQt5.QtNetwork
PyQt5.QtNfc
PyQt5.QtOpenGL
PyQt5.QtPositioning
PyQt5.QtPrintSupport
PyQt5.QtQml
PyQt5.QtQuick
PyQt5.QtQuickWidgets
PyQt5.QtSensors
PyQt5.QtSerialPort
PyQt5.QtSql
PyQt5.QtSvg
PyQt5.QtTest
PyQt5.QtWebChannel
PyQt5.QtWebKit
PyQt5.QtWebKitWidgets
PyQt5.QtWebSockets
PyQt5.QtWidgets
PyQt5.QtX11Extras
PyQt5.QtXml
PyQt5.QtXmlPatterns
PyQt5._QOpenGLFunctions_2_0
PyQt5._QOpenGLFunctions_2_1
PyQt5._QOpenGLFunctions_4_1_Core
PyQt5.uic
PyQt5.uic.Compiler
PyQt5.uic.Compiler.compiler
PyQt5.uic.Compiler.indenter
PyQt5.uic.Compiler.misc
PyQt5.uic.Compiler.proxy_metaclass
PyQt5.uic.Compiler.qobjectcreator
PyQt5.uic.Compiler.qtproxies
PyQt5.uic.Loader
PyQt5.uic.Loader.loader
PyQt5.uic.Loader.qobjectcreator
PyQt5.uic.driver
PyQt5.uic.exceptions
PyQt5.uic.icon_cache
PyQt5.uic.objcreator
PyQt5.uic.port_v2
PyQt5.uic.port_v2.as_string
PyQt5.uic.port_v2.ascii_upper
PyQt5.uic.port_v2.invoke
PyQt5.uic.port_v2.load_plugin
PyQt5.uic.port_v2.proxy_base
PyQt5.uic.port_v2.string_io
PyQt5.uic.port_v3
PyQt5.uic.port_v3.as_string
PyQt5.uic.port_v3.ascii_upper
PyQt5.uic.port_v3.invoke
PyQt5.uic.port_v3.load_plugin
PyQt5.uic.port_v3.proxy_base
PyQt5.uic.port_v3.string_io
PyQt5.uic.properties
PyQt5.uic.pyuic
PyQt5.uic.uiparser
```

It seems the reason is because e.g. `QtWidgets` doesn't have a `__path__` attribute, and so the walk doesn't proceed into `QtWidgets`.

How could I detect *all* classes recursively?

Answer (score 0):

There is no real need to do this, because PyQt already provides API files with all the relevant information. The files look like this:

```
...
PyQt5.QtWidgets.QSpinBox?1(QWidget parent=None)
PyQt5.QtWidgets.QSpinBox.__init__?1(self, QWidget parent=None)
PyQt5.QtWidgets.QSpinBox.value?4() -> int
PyQt5.QtWidgets.QSpinBox.prefix?4() -> QString
PyQt5.QtWidgets.QSpinBox.setPrefix?4(QString)
PyQt5.QtWidgets.QSpinBox.suffix?4() -> QString
PyQt5.QtWidgets.QSpinBox.setSuffix?4(QString)
PyQt5.QtWidgets.QSpinBox.cleanText?4() -> QString
PyQt5.QtWidgets.QSpinBox.singleStep?4() -> int
PyQt5.QtWidgets.QSpinBox.setSingleStep?4(int)
PyQt5.QtWidgets.QSpinBox.minimum?4() -> int
PyQt5.QtWidgets.QSpinBox.setMinimum?4(int)
PyQt5.QtWidgets.QSpinBox.maximum?4() -> int
PyQt5.QtWidgets.QSpinBox.setMaximum?4(int)
...
```

They should be included with a standard PyQt installation, but some platforms may install them separately as part of a "dev" package. Their location on your system can be found like this:

```
>>> os.path.join(QtCore.QLibraryInfo.location(
        QtCore.QLibraryInfo.DataPath), 'qsci/api/python')
>>> '/usr/share/qt/qsci/api/python'
```

The files are mainly intended for use by [QScintilla](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/QScintilla2/) for its auto-completion and call-tips, but of course you can do whatever you like with them. The format of the files is partially explained [here](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/QScintilla2/classQsciAPIs.html#pub-methods):

> Raw API information is read from one or more files. Each API function
>   is described by a single line of text comprising the function's name,
>   followed by the function's optional comma separated parameters
>   enclosed in parenthesis, and finally followed by optional explanatory
>   text.
>
> A function name may be followed by a `?' and a number. The number is
>   used by auto-completion to display a registered QPixmap with the
>   function name.

The "explanatory text" (e.g. `-> int`) is the type of the return value (if any), and the numbers after the function names map to these kinds:

> Class = 1
>   Method = 4
>   Variable = 7
>   Enum = 10

If you want API files for earlier versions of PyQt, you can download the source packages from [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/pyqt/files/).

PS:

I have found that there are a few odd-ball items in `QtCore` that are missing from the API files, namely: `pyqtSignal`, `pyqtProperty` and `pyqtBoundSignal`. It is easy enough to add these yourself, though, if you need them.